# My streamlit app opens in a browser but it is blank and shows 'client connecting' only

Tags: python, streamlit

I deployed my streamlit using github at streamlit.io, and i couldn't open it in my chrome, it keeps showing "[client] Connecting.." and it takes forever.

The error shown in my chrome console:

> WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://apps.streamlitusercontent.com/calvinhartono8/advertising-streamlit/main/Advertising.py/logstream'
> failed:

But, it could be opened in my another account's chrome and some other browsers.

The library I used are:

```
streamlit
pandas
plotly
seaborn
scikit-learn
Pillow
```

Link to my streamlit app: https://share.streamlit.io/calvinhartono8/advertising-streamlit/main/Advertising.py

Comment: It works on my chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off/pause your adblock and tracker extension like (AdBlock, Ghostery etc.) on chrome and reload the page.

The same happened on my chrome too. Then I paused those extensions and it worked. It works smoothly in other browsers too.